# How to assign set @result into another SQL query inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have return stored procedure

```
create procedure t1
    Declare @tablename varchar(1000)
As
Begin
    Declare @result varchar(50), @t1 varchar(60)
    Set @result = 'select * from' + @tablename

    Exec(@result)

    set @t1 = (select * into #temp from @result)
```

I am stuck how to pass `@result` variable to `@t1` inside the stored procedure.

I wanted to pass `@result` output to another SQL query

Comment: Write the into command into @result and execute that

Comment: You need a **space** when setting `@result` between the `from` keyword and the `@tablename` - otherwise you end up with a statement like `select * fromcustomer` and that's definitely not valid ...

Comment: FYI, that code is horrendously dangerous as it's wide open to injection attacks. You *need* to properly quote your object name(s) and possibly validate it too.

Comment: "I wanted to pass @result output to another SQL query" what do you actually want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

The temp table structure is not fixed it will vary as per different tablename.wanted to create temp table dynamically